# How to upgrade Android app in Google Play without old cirtificate and private key

Tags: google-play, upgrade

I am trying to upgrade app in Google Play. But shown error message i.e. related to certificate. I have not any certificate and key for that. This is all missing, Only I have a source code. Please guide me to upgrade app with different way. Is this possible in iPhone, so i think is trick available in Android also. Thank You! Very much in advance. - Ranjit

Comment: Please give me a help for that...

Answer (score 0):

You have probably figured out by now that it is **Not possible to upgrade a Google Play Store App without the same package name and the identical certificate.** The following is an excerpt to an article I found that helps explain why. [Link to the original article.](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/06/things-that-cannot-change.html)

**Your package name and certificate:**

The most obvious and visible of these is the “manifest package name,” the unique name you give to your application in its AndroidManifest.xml. The name uses a Java-language-style naming convention, with Internet domain ownership helping to avoid name collisions. For example, since Google owns the domain “google.com”, the manifest package names of all of our applications should start with “com.google.” It’s important for developers to follow this convention in order to avoid conflicts with other developers.

Once you publish your application under its manifest package name, this is the unique identity of the application forever more. **Switching to a different name results in an entirely new application, one that can’t be installed as an update to the existing application.**

Just as important as the manifest package name is the certificate that application is signed with. The signing certificate represents the author of the application. **If you change the certificate an application is signed with, it is now a different application because it comes from a different author.** This different application can’t be uploaded to Market as an update to the original application, nor can it be installed onto a device as an update.

The exact behavior the user sees when installing an application that has changed in one of these two ways is different:

If the manifest package name has changed, the new application will be installed alongside the old application, so they both co-exist on the user’s device at the same time.

If the signing certificate changes, trying to install the new application on to the device will fail until the old version is uninstalled.

If you change the signing certificate of your application, you should always change its manifest package name as well to avoid failures when it’s installed.

**Your AndroidManifest.xml is a public API**
More than just your package name that is immutable. A major function of the AndroidManifest.xml is essentially to declare a public API from your application for use by other applications and the Android system. Every component you declare in the manifest that is not private (that is whose android:exported state is true) should be treated as a public API and never changed in a way that breaks compatibility.

A subtle but important aspect of what constitutes a break in compatibility is the **android:name attribute of your activity, service, and receiver components.** This can be surprising because we think of android:name as pointing to the private code implementing our application, but it is also (in combination with the manifest package name) the official unique public name for that component, as represented by the ComponentName class.

Changing the component name inside of an application can have negative consequences for your users. Some examples are:

If the name of a main activity of your application is changed, any shortcuts the user made to it will no longer work. A shortcut is an Intent that directly specifies the ComponentName it should run.
There are two main kinds of Intents:

Implicit Intents only specify “what” they should match, using actions, categories, data, MIME types, and so on. The exact components that they will find are only determined at run-time, by the Package Manager matching it against the current applications.

Explicit Intents specify a single explicit “who” they should match, through a ComponentName. Regardless of whatever else is in the Intent, it is only associated with the exact manifest package name and class name as given in its ComponentName.

Both of these types of Intents are important to how Android interacts with your application.

The ComponentName is the public unique name of the components you declare in your manifest, and must not change if they are visible to other applications.

In conclusion: There are some parts of your application that can not change. Please be careful.

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/06/things-that-cannot-change.html

Comment: Can you try to shorten the answer, please?

Comment: I'm not sure, I know just leaving links to information is frowned upon and I don't want to take anything away from the authors advice / explanation. How would you recommend I proceed to make this a better answer? :) The first paragraph sums it all up but the rest tells us why. Thanks for your input.

Comment: Yes, you definitely do not want to just post a link, but try to summarize to make it better to read.

Comment: I took out some of the fluff and highlighted the main points of what should not be altered when updating an app. Thank you for the advice.

Comment: Thanks. Always try to keep the person who asked the question and user in mind. That's the whole point of SO.